# LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 - on rake db:create

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When i run `rake db:create`, I get this error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
/Users/vitorqueiroz/dev/pipeline/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/vitorqueiroz/dev/pipeline/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I had to mannualy install mysql2 gem because the gemfile specifies the version '0.3.20'

I ran 
`gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20' -- --srcdir=/usr/local/include/mysql`

Bundle install runs fine, and says everything is installed.

`bundle list mysql2` evaluates to:

```
/Users/vitorqueiroz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.20
```

--

Any alternatives?

Comment: Thanks! I don't think there is any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

to be sure that bundled gems are loaded.

https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Comment: thanks for the reply @mrzasa, pointing to --srcdir=/usr/local/include/mysql was my problem. the mysql2 gem wont install properly in the project if you have mysql 8 version installed locally. I had to remove it and install mysql version 5.7, then reinstalled my mysql2 gem normally, and everything worked fine.